# Why doesn't this work - JOptionPane - Reading Integer Value

Tags: java, swing, command, joptionpane

So i'm working on my project and I want to implement commands such as "/heal value" but when I debug this code it prints what I input in the console but not effect is given? Am I doing this correctly?

Here is the full class

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Commands {
  //Variables
  String command; //The variable that controls each command
  int[] blockName; //Each block is a int[]
  String number; //The block stack amount number - you only need to worry about /heal
  String amount; //The amount of health you want to give the player
  public static boolean open = false; //Detects whether the command window is open

  public Commands() {
  }

  public void tick() {
    if(open) {
      //create a JOptionPane so you can enter a command
      command = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Command");
      //Should check to see if command matchs any of the commands
      loadCommands();
      //prints the command input
      if(command != "" || command != null) { 
        System.out.println(Component.username + ": " + command + " Called");
      }
      //then sets open to false so that the JOptionPane. You dont need to worry about this
      open = false;
    }
  }

  public void loadCommands() {
    //This is the list of commands
    try {
      //This is the /give command
      if(command.equals("/give " + blockName + " " + number)) {
        Component.inventory.holdingID = blockName;
        Component.inventory.holdingIDStack = Integer.parseInt(number);
        System.out.println(command);
      }

      //This is the /heal command I am using to debug
      if(command.equals("/heal " + amount)) {
        Component.character.health += Integer.parseInt(amount);
        System.out.println(command);
      }
      //This is the/kill command to kill the play this too does not work?
      if(command.equals("/kill ")) {
        Component.character.hurt(999);
        System.out.println(command);
      }
    } catch(NullPointerException e) { 
      /*This is here because without it a NullPointerException appears in the console and the JOptionPane can't be closed */
    }
  }

/* How I know it doesn't work is because it doesnt print out the command twice like
 * it is meant to...
 */

}
```

Comment: if you need this:
 }catch(NullPointerException e) { 
    /*This is here because without
     it a NullPointerException appears in the console 
     and the JOptionPane can't be closed */
    }
that means you are using a non instantiated variable. you are just hiding the exception, doesn't mean it doesn't occur anymore. you'll need to check where the exception is thrown, and instantiate the variable that causes it

Comment: amount String is null!!!

Comment: it is thrown at the if(command.equals("command here") {

Comment: Move `loadCommands();` *after* you make the check `if(command != "" || command != null)`. Your `command` string is `null` probably.

Comment: The command string is being set to whatever the input is on JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Command"); So it can not possibly be null because the /kill command works